# Teradata conversion of seconds to hours

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have a little problem with the conversion of seconds to hours in Teradata..

```
CAST((TRUNC(seconds/3600) (FORMAT '99')) AS VARCHAR(10)) ||':'|| 
CAST((TRUNC((seconds MOD 3600)/60) (FORMAT '99')) AS VARCHAR(10)) ||':'|| 
CAST((TRUNC(seconds MOD 60) (FORMAT '99')) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS SecToHours
```

I need to convert seconds to minutes and hours in the format 00:00:00 but now if I have more than 100 hours instead of 100 hours getting the result **
I don't want a format of '999'.

Awaited results:

hours:minutes:seconds

00:00:59

00:59:59

09:59:59

99:59:59

100:59:59

Is it a possibility ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply change the FORMAT using optional digits.

This is a simplified version, if `seconds` is not a DECIMAL you might remove the `TRUNC`, too:

```
(TRUNC( seconds/3600)         (FORMAT 'ZZ99')) ||
(TRUNC((seconds MOD 3600)/60) (FORMAT ':99' )) ||
(TRUNC( seconds MOD 60)       (FORMAT ':99' )) AS SecToHours
```

Or use an INTERVAL (if less than 10000 hours):

```
seconds * INTERVAL '0000:00:01'  HOUR TO SECOND
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the hours portion.  A `case` statement can solve the problem:

```
(CASE WHEN seconds < 3600*10 THEN CAST((TRUNC(seconds/3600) (FORMAT '99')) AS VARCHAR(10))
      ELSE CAST(TRUNC(seconds/3600) AS VARCHAR(10))
 END) ||':'|| 
. . .
```